# datagrid on a background picture

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, wpfdatagrid

can someone tell me how to put the datagrid on a background picture. i set a picture as my program background but if i put the datagrid on it i get an error (the picture should not be at that place) but if i move it to the bottom i dont get an error but when program starts, the background is lost-it's white. Here is the code:

```
<Grid>
    <Image  Grid.RowSpan="2" Stretch="UniformToFill" Source="/MieteDasAuto;component/Images/texture.jpg" Visibility="Visible"/>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="3*">
        </RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <DataGrid Name="vMieten" Margin="20" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" ItemsSource="{Binding}"/>
```

Comment: firstly,you can't put image at there, you must put it after  `<Grid.RowDefinitions>`. "the background is lost-it's white" means what? and what's your demand? set bg for a grid,and put datagrid on it,and datagrid's bd is transparent?

Comment: i´ve tried putting it after <Grid.RowDefinitions> but then in the designer view it seems that everything is all right but when i start the program it turns white and that meana there is no background at all, it just a white window with a grid and no background

Comment: could you post a image of your expected output?

Comment: i can´t i have to have 10 reputation in order to post pictures. but it´s like this. the whole window background should be a image from my computer and on that bg(picture) should be a datagrid. The funny thing is that it looks all right in a designer but when i start it the bg goes away...

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this helps you: [DataGrid.BackgroundImage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.windows.forms.datagrid.backgroundimage%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) or [Turning a WPF DataGrid background image on and off?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13509902/turning-a-wpf-datagrid-background-image-on-and-off)